# Android 'Firebase' member go to group with name off node, owner get message to allow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with 'Firebase database' for my android app. A authenticated user add a node to database, this node is the chatroom.

First question: how do I make the user to the owner of the group?

Here add groupe:

```
 mReference = database.getReference("groups");
            groupe grdata= new groupe();
            grdata.setGroupeID(mReference.child("Chatroom").push().getKey());
            grdata.setOwnerID(id);
            grdata.setOwnerName(sharedPreferences.getString("vorname_nachname",""));
            grdata.setGroupeName("Chatroom");
            mReference.child("Chatroom").setValue(grdata);
```

the owner share the name off the chatroom, the user can now add to the chatroom.

```
mReference.child("chatroom")
```

Second question: how get the owner a message and how allow the user to go into the group?

Here picture off database
[image: How allow Uid ....z2 to go in chatroom]

Comment: There is no way to answer this without seeing the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem you are asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I highly recommend reading that link, as it contains many tips that will increase the changes someone will be able to help.

Comment: When i find the button to change , i do it..

Comment: If you are looking for the [edit] button, it's below your question (or click on it in this comment).

Comment: Thanks for adding that code. The concept of owning a group is specific to your application. We have no way to know what it means without you showing us enough information, possibly how ownership relates to `GroupeData` or how it shows up in the JSON in your database. But I honestly am just guessing at this point. There is not enough information in your question right now to be able to answer the questions. Please [construct a minimal, complete, self-contained, example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the link contains some great information on how to do this, which helps us help you.